# Date Formatter is not working

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I have this  string

let myDate = "10 Jan 2018 06:31:01 PM"

I want to convert it in two string

1. date(dd)
2. month and year(MMM yyyy)

for this I'm using this code

```
let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
 //first converting string into date

 timeFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MM yyyy hh:mm:ss a"
 let date = timeFormatter.date(from: myDate)
 // date into string

 let str = timeFormatter.string(from: date!)
 print(str )
 // know changing resultant string into desire format 

 timeFormatter.dateFormat = "dd"
 let strdate = timeFormatter.date(from: str)
 timeFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM yyyy"
 let fullDate = timeFormatter.date(from: str)
 cell.lblFullDate.text = "\(String(describing: strdate))"
 cell.lblDate.text = "\(String(describing: fullDate))"
```

when I run it, compiler get stuck on this line

```
let date = timeFormatter.date(from: myDate)
```

because this  date formate is not correct

```
timeFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MM yyyy hh:mm:ss a"
```

what DateFormatter should I use for this?

Comment: did you import `Foundation` - `import Foundation`

Comment: *get stuck* how? And `strdate` and `fullDate` will be always `nil` with this code. Your approach to get the two different strings from a date is completely wrong.

Comment: yoiu need to use `dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss a` instead of `dd MM yyyy hh:mm:ss a`, the month format is  `MM (01) MMM(Jan) MMMM(January)`

Comment: check my answer  I added clearly the date format

Comment: @Anbu.karthik  I have already tried this format "dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss a" but not working

Comment: @DeeptiRaghav - are you checked my answer, your second and third dateformatter is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you faced the error then check before assign

```
 guard let earnDate = single["earndate"] as? String else { return }
```

> Your are try to get the two different strings from a date is completely wrong.

do like

```
    let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
    timeFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss a"
    let date = timeFormatter.date(from: "10 Jan 2018 06:31:01 PM")
     timeFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM yyyy"
    let str = timeFormatter.string(from: date!)
   let finalVal = str.components(separatedBy: "-")
    print(finalVal.first ?? "" )
    print(finalVal.last ?? "" )
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your code is all sorts of messed up, you are throwing `String`s and `Date`s everywhere, you should start over step by step.

1. parse the date into a `date` variable using a proper formatter
2. create a string representation from that `date` based on a different format (using a different formatter or changing the format on the existing one)
3. do step 2 again with another format for your second output

In particular the `str` should be removed completely.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
timeFormatter.dateFormat = "DD"
let strdate = timeFormatter.string(from: date!)

timeFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM yyyy"
let fullDate = timeFormatter.string(from: date!)
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: if you change the dateformatter you  will get the exact answer

Comment: @Anbu.karthik is smthg wrng?

Comment: yes bro, once you changed the `timeFormatter` the updated dateformatter will availbale in the format so based on your answer second one returns nil

Comment: @Anbu.karthik Yeah but I stored the desired output in variable. OP can use this variable to assign the label.

Comment: I am getting this string  10 Jan 2018 06:31:01 PM not this 2018-01-10 13:01:01 +0000

Comment: @DeeptiRaghav Yeah I am using `10 Jan 2018 06:31:01 PM`

Comment: @DeeptiRaghav - always the  OP date format has no proper format in dateformatter

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do this

```
guard let timeString = single["earndate"] as? String else { return }

let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
timeFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MM yyyy hh:mm:ss a"
let date = timeFormatter.date(from: timeString)
let str = timeFormatter.string(from: date!)
print(str)
timeFormatter.dateFormat = "dd"
let strdate = timeFormatter.date(from: str)
timeFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM yyyy"
let fullDate = timeFormatter.date(from: str)
cell.lblFullDate.text = "\(String(describing: strdate))"
cell.lblDate.text = "\(String(describing: fullDate))"
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not post any error message you get, and the code you wrote for converting the string to date using the DateFormatter is correct, I would suggest you check your `(single["earndate"] as? String)`.

Which probably returning `nil`, and making your compiler to get "stuck".

you can use guard statement like:

```
   guard let earnDate = single["earndate"] as? String else { return }
   var date = "";
   if earnDate {
         date = timeFormatter.date(from: earnDate)
   }
```